# PhantomJS - Capture screen to HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement or ImageData

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Is it possible with PhantomJS to **capture** a web page screen **without saving** it to the file system?

I need this because I want to make some post processing (color scheme detection) with the page screenshot.

The color detection is also made with JS .(https://github.com/leeoniya/RgbQuant.js) and can handle `HTMLImageElement`, `HTMLCanvasElement`, `ImageData` or `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

Here is the PhantomJS API, but the `render` method only supports a file path: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: Probably not if you want to use PhantomJS. You can always replace the current `page.content` with only an image with a file path to the save image, then inject RgbQuant, make your adjustments and render again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Artjom B. for your solution in the comment. It worked fine.
First I created the screenshot of the page, and saved it to the folder `screenshots` with an `html file` that **includes this screenshot**.

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    // Make screenshot and save it to './screenshots'
    var rel_path = 'screenshots/' + btoa(url) + '_' + (new Date().getTime());

    // Image path
    var img_path = rel_path + '.png';

    // HTML page path
    var html_path = rel_path + '.html';

    // Make screenshot
    page.render(img_path);

    // Create webpage with the image, but take the absolute path.
    fs.write(html_path, '<html><body><img id="image" src="' + 'file:///' + fs.absolute(img_path) + '"/></body></html>', 'w');
});
```

After that I opend the created file again with phantom. Loaded the image by the id=image and performed my RGB-Quantification.

```
p.open('file:///' + html_path, function start(status) {
    console.log('[RGB-QUANTIFICATION]: ' + self.url);

    // Inject image quantification library
    p.injectJs('ext/rgbquant.js');

    // Generate color palette
    var colors = p.evaluate(function () {
        var rgb_quant_settings = {colors: 5, method: 2, initColors: 4096, minHueCols: 0};
        var rgb_quant = new RgbQuant(rgb_quant_settings);
        rgb_quant.sample(document.getElementById('image'));
        return rgb_quant.palette(true);
    });

    ...

});
```